# PerformanceAnalytics and Annual Charting

Tags: performanceanalytics, annualized

I have seen a charts that look's like
[image: Annual Charting]

Is it possible to do something like this with PerformanceAnalytics or is there any other package for doing this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you give the reference or be a little bit more specific what these different blocks represent?

Comment: I would like to show the outperformance of 2 or more investments against the same benchmark. I would like to reset on a yearly base to get better informations how it performs in the particular year.

Comment: Hello, after trying a little bit I have two approaches. Having different timeseries and plot them in multiple plot from left to right. The other one is creating one timeseries and reset the performance when reaching a given date.